# Don't Remind Me to "Consider Accept Answers" on StackExchange

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange

Being a veteran SO user and an active SE participator, it is quite-- erm, how to put it nicely--*amusing* to see me being reminded again and again to "not forget to mark an accepted answer" whenever I upvote one, especially at the time when I am joining a new SE site and casting my first upvote on that site.

Since somehow SO should have all the my data already, is it possible to distinguish between a real first time user, as opposed to a veteran SO user joining a new site, so that we won't have to be bothered by all the announcements, reminders that are normally reserved for the newbies?

Comment: Not an essential feature, and would result in unnecessary (albeit minor) complications, but...it is pretty cute and neat.

Comment: I've also noticed this and while it is irritating, it doesn't last as long as you participate in the site.

Comment: @ChrisF - but why should anyone be irritated at all if they have the means to fix it?  Just use a bit to indicate newness instead of rep directly (if they aren't already), then flip the bit immediately for people who have been on other sites long enough to learn the ropes.

Comment: @tvanfosson - it's because I *know* about accepting answers or leaving comments & it only mild irritation. In fact I think I only really noticed the first time I voted on one of the new site's meta site.

Answer (score 5):

It would be nice to use a [Jimi Hendrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Are_You_Experienced) bit to determine "new" user status instead of rep directly.  The "experienced" bit would be set when your rep on any one of the related sites is over the "new" user threshold.  Note that this wouldn't apply to privileges, just the nag messages that new users see.

Comment: The Janis Joplin approach is also nice, never show nags during _summertime_